# Pulseaudio over network - change output on-the-fly

Tags: linux, networking, audio, alsa, pulseaudio

I successfully configured PulseAudio server and client to send audio over network.
It uses direct connection: http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Network/#index1h2

I'd like to have a possibility to switch between client and server sound card i.e. temporarily disable network stream and go back to internal sound device.

Using module-tunnel-sink I could simply move sink-input to desired device but is not an option since it doesn't work well with Flash:

> they lead me to believe that Flash is somehow sending the sound to PulseAudio in such a way that it creates a lot of network traffic (think lots of tiny packets, not bandwidth); this overwhelms the network "tunnel" PulseAudio

With direct connection I have to restart the application every time I want to switch the output.

Any idea how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked a `pavucontrol`? It's a GUI for controlling pulseaudio streams (volume and sinks). I use it to switch between different soundcards. At the very least it might help you check whether you're using the right commands to switch the sink in `pactl`.

Comment: Yes I did, my configuration is correct. As I've said I can't switch sink because using direct connection entire stream is being forwarded to the server - nothing goes through the client's sinks.

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to have a possibility to switch between client and server sound card i.e. temporarily disable network stream and go back to internal sound device.

Then you cannot use a direct connection - that will only allow you to change the configuration on the remote.

Instead, create a new sink that either connect by [tunnel](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Network/#index2h2) or by [RTP](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Network/#index3h2) or a similar module to the remote. For RTP etc. you also need a set up on the remote.

Then you can just switch sinks on the local computer, and choose between a local sink, and the remote forwarding sink.